# Select image from gallery using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Recently i have started learning `Kotlin`. After having some basic functionality i am stuck with image picker.

Does there any specific way to select an image from gallery and camera using `Kotlin`? Or should i implement in our normal Java code and then call it from `Kotlin` file?

**Java code** :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

Any other difference to perform this operation using `Kotlin`?

Comment: What is the problem, u are facing?

Comment: u can write your whole project in Kotlin, u won't even need a single java file.

Answer (score 17):

Here a sample function code for selecting image and capture image:

```
 fun selectImageInAlbum() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE_IN_ALBUM)
        }
    }
 fun takePhoto() {
        val intent1 = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        if (intent1.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent1, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO)
        }
    }
 companion object {
        private val REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 0
        private val REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE_IN_ALBUM = 1
    }
```

Also don't forget to add this to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I hope i can help

Answer (score 5):

Now that `startActivityForResult()` is Deprecated, this is the new way.
First, Do this inside `onCreate`

Kotlin:

```
    val selectImageIntent = registerForActivityResult(GetContent())
    { uri ->
        imageView.setImageURI(uri)
    }
```

Java :

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> selectImageIntent = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
                imageView.setImageURI(uri);
            }
        });
```

And call `selectImageIntent.launch("image/*")` to launch gallery.

Comment: how to convert the uri to multipart or file ?
as i need multipart to send to server.

Answer (score 4):

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.type = "image/*"
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE)

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write it at Kotlin too.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.type = "image/*"
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

Comment: Thn wht about `onActivityForResult()`? can we write same in kotlin also?

Comment: You can write any javacode as a kotlin analog. You even can copy javacode to kotlin file to convert javacode to kotlincode

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, requestcode)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fun Fragment.openGalleryForPickingImage(code: Int) {
    Intent().apply {
        type = "image/*"
        action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(this, getString(R.string.select_file)), code)
    }
}
```

The problem with it, is that the function to get real path doesn't work because content resolver doesn't find the columnIndex corresponding to  MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
Instead, you need to do:

```
fun Fragment.openGalleryForPickingImage(code: Int) {
    Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    ).apply {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(this, getString(R.string.select_file)), code)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin :

```
fun getPhoto() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    startActivityForResult(intent,1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the tutorial https://www.viralpatel.net/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/

inside `onActivityResult` add this code

```
if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data != null){
            val selectedImage = data?.data
            val filePathColumn = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)

            val cursor =
                contentResolver.query(selectedImage!!, filePathColumn, null, null, null)!!
            cursor.moveToFirst()

            val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])
            mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
            var f = File(mediaPath)
            var filename = f.getName()
            mediaPathArray!!.add(mediaPath)
            Log.d("filename", filename)
            Log.d("imgpath", mediaPath)
            image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage)))
            cursor.close()
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).